How can we pass the User ID within DFP
Is it possible to pass the user ID or other user-specific data when a user clicks on a digital banner in your app using Google Ad Manager (formerly DFP). If yes, then how can we achieve this.
Please help.!
Currently, there is no possible solutions to this.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
